# $target = $(target) in javascript\jQuery. Need explanation of syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The sample code mentioned below is a part of jQuery Countdown plugin by Keith Wood. Can some explain this

```
_attachCountdown: function(target, options) {
        var $target = $(target);
        if ($target.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
            return;
        }
        $target.addClass(this.markerClassName);
        var inst = {options: $.extend({}, options),
            _periods: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]};
        $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        this._changeCountdown(target);
    }
```

Is there a reason specifically defining $target or its just same as our simple variables like var target.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a simple variable, `$` is just added to indicate to the code reader that a jQuery collection is stored inside. Javascript is quite "lenient" with variable names, the `$` has no special meaning (opposed to PHP where it is needed before every variable name).

This method (`var $target=$(target);`) is used to save the result of `$(target)` (the jQuery collection itself, storing `target`) into a variable, so the jQuery collection does not need to be created everytime it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The `$` in JavaScript is valid for variable names and has no significance on its functionality.

The original author was probably saving two keystrokes (or four if you include shift) and renaming it for convenience, but left the `$` prefix to symbolize it is a jQuery-wrapped object. (Think of it like the old [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) facsimile.)

Comment: Not convenience as much as speed. `target` can be a selector, in which case executing the selector four times is not quite optimal. Better run the selector once and cache it. Saving keystrokes is secondary to that.

Comment: @Amadan: Though what you've stated is very true, more often than not when you find occurrences of this it's usually for laziness and not efficiency (efficiency is usually a case of serendipity). ;-) -- **EDIT:** Though, I suppose with the use of `$target` over `$t`, you're probably right it was the intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

By the following code:

```
var $target = $(target);
```

the author of the script assigns to the following variable:

```
$target
```

the result of the following expression:

```
$(target)
```

which is the result of `jQuery()` function (`$()` is only an alias for it) being passed the `target` variable.

So, to sum up, what you have here is:

- `target` JS variable (probably some string determining the selector),
- `$` JS function (basically `jQuery` function, but the `$` alias is often used for writing shorter code),
- `$target` JS variable that stores the result of the `$(target)` (or `jQuery(target)`) expression